# Problema na utilização do QPixmap.scaled

Tags: python, gui

Recentemente estou aprendendo a utilizar o `PyQt4`, porém surgiu uma dúvida na utilização da linha de código para modificar a escala de uma imagem:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(743, 510)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 430, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.foto = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.foto.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 390, 700, 27))
        self.foto.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Diretorio"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 26, 671, 341))
        self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.horizontalSlider = QtGui.QSlider(Form)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 430, 601, 18))
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(255)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalSlider"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 450, 71, 17))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.abrirfoto)
        #self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.threshold)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Testando", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Abrir", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Threshold", None))

    def abrirfoto(self):

        img = self.foto.text()
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img))
        QtGui.QPixmap.scaled(671,341,0,0)
```

E retorna o erro:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>     QPixmap.scaled(int, int, Qt.AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode=Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.TransformationMode transformMode=Qt.FastTransformation): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QPixmap'
>     QPixmap.scaled(QSize, Qt.AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode=Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.TransformationMode transformMode=Qt.FastTransformation): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QPixmap'

Comment: Não dá pra fazer scaled "solto" no código. Você tem que chamar o scaled em um pixmap já  existente. Tentou `QtGui.QPixmap(img).scaled(671,341,0,0)`? (não sei se dá pra encadear assim na PyQt. se não der, atribua a uma variável, aplique o scaled e depois ponha no label)

Comment: Criei outra variável e apliquei o scaled, deu certo aqui. obrigado pela ajuda =)

Comment: Poste abaixo como resposta a sua solução, explique o que mudou e marque como aceita, assim fecha legal a questão e pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Eu adicionei uma variável na função `abrirfoto`, que estava associada a função `.scaled`, ficando dessa forma:

```
def abrirfoto(self): 
    img = self.foto.text()
    imagem = QtGui.QPixmap(img) 
    imagem1 = imagem.scaled(671,341,QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation) 
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagem1))
```